# Exclude groups containing just one row instance

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a pandas table like below with `groupby` applied to get Groups 0, 1 and 2 as follows:

| Group 0 | Group 1 | Group 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 577.5000 | 6 |
|  |  | 894.8700 | 2 |
|  | X2 | 2697.3100 | 48 |
|  |  | 2697.3100 | 1 |
|  | B3 | 2697.3100 | 30 |
| B | RO2 | 92.46 | 3 |
| C | C12 | 34.2700 | 9 |
|  |  | 39.2700 | 3 |
| D | X55 | 4.1251 | 9 |

How do I filter out rows having just one group variation i.e. Below is how the final DF should look like:

| Group 0 | Group 1 | Group 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | X1 | 577.5000 | 6 |
|  |  | 894.8700 | 2 |
|  | X2 | 2697.3100 | 48 |
|  |  | 2697.3100 | 1 |
|  | B3 | 2697.3100 | 30 |
| C | C12 | 34.2700 | 9 |
|  |  | 39.2700 | 3 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep groups where at least one value from `Group 0` is duplicated:

```
out = df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Group 0').duplicated(keep=False)]
print(out)

# Output
                         Count
Group 0 Group 1 Group 2       
A       X1      577.50       6
                894.87       2
        X2      2697.31     48
                2697.31      1
        B3      2697.31     30
C       C12     34.27        9
                39.27        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

Only considering the first group:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['Group 0'])['Group 0'].size().gt(1)]
```

Considering all groups:

```
out = df[df.groupby(['Group 0', 'Group 1', 'Group 2'])['Group 0'].size().gt(1)]
```

Comment: I get the error 'Column not found: `Group 0`'. I believe this is because the column `Group 0` is under the index (groupby). I even ran the query after using `reset_index()`

Comment: Then use `groupby(level=[...])`

Comment: But check the other answer, it's probably a better approach if you only need to consider group 0